# Angular 6 Laravel 5.6 shows 405 methods when use httpOptions in service call

Tags: angular, laravel, angular6

My intention is to generate an object (actually objects within object) in Angular and send the same using services, so that Laravel API can take the data & process the same (insert the data send by Angular). I have successfully generate the objects within object. See the console log as below:

> > {"request":{"data":"DeTurgVx6Oyh0is0TZMJncHHJh6JBevZbgW1XL2s1uvXk7qKKMRlJ6FJ1AYAiNSxHlA0JLO9pyQgYFBWQHnliOPVHsaFtsVZ8emmsSS7MOfKBP6x2CZqCMWegRMdoaV9TJxKSEsKhD48frwiOwwD4GKChYiX0HfZKp5Wm6aQCOSuXC7HyXb+KZjbhWsmispUhz21FBf0T6NWaPmOgf/eWtMgCu2hPYj7IyrGLEmt8QwmCn79VTDmNnAeM7zecXqg/TPu1wqoYrBXq8IHUQ9+CA==","salt":"YWRnaHJ0eXVwb2Vxd2VkZg=="}}

Now, I want to send the data through services so that Laravel can take this. To do the same, I did the following. In this case, the data is submitted with post method however, the data is not inserting into database as I thought I did not passed `Content-Type': 'application/json` with the services as option.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { User } from '../app/shared/models/user.model'; 
export class RegistrationService {
private rootUrl = environment.api;
private httpOptions: any;
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
    };
}
registerUser(form){
  var formValues = JSON.stringify(form);
  return this.http.post(this.rootUrl+'register', formValues);
}
```

So, to rectify the above, I attached `this.httpOptions` with the api call within the service as below but it shows me `405 method not allowed`.

```
return this.http.post(this.rootUrl+'register', formValues, this.httpOptions);
```

To overcome the problem, I attached the below code is Laravel `index.php` however, this does not solve the issue.

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Request-With');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
$app->run();
```

Can someone tell me how can I solve the issue?

This is the *route* `web.php` in Laravel:

```
$router->get('/', function () use ($router) {
    return $router->app->version();
});
$router->group([
    'prefix' => 'api',
    'middleware' => ['XSS'],
    ], 
function () use ($router) {
  $router->post('register', ['uses' => 'UserController@register']);
});
```

Below is the API called when showing 405 method:

> > Request URL: http://localhost/projectName/api/register
> >     Request Method: OPTIONS
> >     Status Code: 405 Method Not Allowed
> >     Remote Address: [::1]:80
> >     Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

*Here is the response header:*

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Request-With
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Allow: POST
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Tue, 08 Jan 2019 05:16:44 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Comment: Show us the route you're trying to `POST` to

Comment: @devk route code inserted into my query. Please check.

Comment: When you post the request from your Angular app, can you check what URL it's posting to and paste it here?

Comment: @devk Modified my query. Please check the calling URL at bottom.

Comment: @devk I have provide you a wrong info. I'm using `web.php` for route.